# Программное изменение высоты строки JTable

Tags: swing, jtable

Подскажите имеется форма

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    private int colThread=0;
    MainThread mt=new MainThread("Поток - 1");

    public MainFrame()  
    {
        setSize(300,300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JTable jTable=new JTable(20,4);
        jTable.setRowHeight(20);
        jTable.addMouseListener(new RightMouse());
        add(jTable);
    }
}
```

И имеется класс слушателя нажатия правой клавиши мыши

```
public class RightMouse extends MouseAdapter{

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (e.getButton()==MouseEvent.BUTTON3)
        {
            JPopupMenu popupMenu = new TableMenu(e);
            popupMenu.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
        }
    }

    private class TableMenu extends JPopupMenu
    {
        JMenuItem anMenu;

        public TableMenu(MouseEvent event) {

            this.anMenu = new JMenuItem("Увеличить ширину строки");
            add(anMenu);
            this.anMenu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (event.getComponent() instanceof JTable)
                    {
                        JTable table = (JTable) event.getComponent();
                        try {
                            table.setRowHeight(table.getRowHeight() + 10);
                        }catch (IllegalArgumentException err)
                        {
                            table.setRowHeight(10);
                        }

                    }
                }
            });

            this.anMenu = new JMenuItem("Уменьшить ширину строки");
            add(anMenu);
            this.anMenu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (event.getComponent() instanceof JTable)
                    {
                        JTable table = (JTable) event.getComponent();
                        try {
                            table.setRowHeight(table.getRowHeight() - 10);
                        }catch (IllegalArgumentException err)
                        {
                            table.setRowHeight(10);
                        }

                    }
                }
            });
        }   

    }
}
```

Вопрос состоит в том как мне можно сделать, чтобы можно было изменять высоту определенной строки, на которой в данный можент указатель мыши, а не все строки в таблице

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int row = table.rowAtPoint(event.getPoint());
```

Помогла следующая статья
https://javaswing.wordpress.com/2009/09/16/jtable_right_button_selection/